# Windows Task Scheduler - Task Won't Die

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a task scheduled to run daily that executes a .bat file and I have checked the options for ending the task after an hour and forcing it to stop if it does not end when requested to, but it runs indefinitely until I manually kill it. Any ideas? (I do not want to use pskill in my script). Script below:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -U username -P password _Q "BACKUP DATABASE x to y"
net use z: "\\server1\project"
cd C:\trial1
copy * "Z:\backups"
net use z: /delete
exit
```

Comment: can you please post your script

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: Use /delete, the backslash makes it look like a pathname.  I suppose it gets stuck trying to display an error.  Hmm.  While you are at it, avoid net use completely and copy to `\\server1\project\backups`.  And make sure it works before trying to turn it into a task.

Comment: The sys admin asked that I use net use, but I worked with him and am now doing a direct copy like you suggest. Testing now.

Comment: That works! Thanks @HansPassant

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for the answer! See below:

> Taking away 'net use' and just directly copying to the server cleared up some error that the task scheduler was getting stuck on.